# NiFi convert avro to JSON array format with nested array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

New to Nifi and looking to see if we can convert results of SQL to JSON in the requested format.
SQL result is :

| member_id | field2 | total | tax | ship | partnum | price | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 874450963 | 24017 | 173.95 | 0 | 0 | 015935966 | 42 | 1 |
| 874450963 | 24017 | 173.95 | 0 | 0 | 000756009 | 32 | 1 |
| 874450963 | 24017 | 173.95 | 0 | 0 | 012179293 | 99.95 | 1 |

The out of the box result looks like this using either ***ConvertRecord*** or ***ConvertAvroToJSON*** process:

```json
[
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "015935966",
    "PRICE": "42",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "000756009",
    "PRICE": "32",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "012179293",
    "PRICE": "99.95",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  }
]
```

Request is to group these and have the partnum, price and quantity as an array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0",
    "itemDetails": [
      {
        "PARTNUM": "015935966",
        "PRICE": "42",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "000756009",
        "PRICE": "32",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "012179293",
        "PRICE": "99.95",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do we do this?

Thanks!

Searched forum and didn't see anything similar.

New Scenario:

```json
[
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "015935966",
    "PRICE": "42",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "000756009",
    "PRICE": "32",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "PARTNUM": "012179293",
    "PRICE": "99.95",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "25008",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874221898",
    "PARTNUM": "013519828",
    "PRICE": "16.95",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "83.80",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "25008",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874221898",
    "PARTNUM": "012625445",
    "PRICE": "5.95",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "83.80",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "25008",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874221898",
    "PARTNUM": "017219152",
    "PRICE": "54.95",
    "QUANTITY": "1",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "83.80",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0"
  }
]
```

Result should be:

```json
[
  {
    "FIELD2": "24017",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874450963",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "173.95",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0",
    "itemDetails": [
      {
        "PARTNUM": "015935966",
        "PRICE": "42",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "000756009",
        "PRICE": "32",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "012179293",
        "PRICE": "99.95",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "FIELD2": "25008",
    "MEMBER_ID": "874221898",
    "TIMEPLACED": null,
    "TOTALPRODUCT": "183.80",
    "TOTALSHIPPING": "0",
    "TOTALTAX": "0",
    "itemDetails": [
      {
        "PARTNUM": "013519828",
        "PRICE": "16.95",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "012625445",
        "PRICE": "5.95",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      },
      {
        "PARTNUM": "017219152",
        "PRICE": "54.95",
        "QUANTITY": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be carrying out this conversion by using ***JoltTransformJSON*** process with the following specification :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&", // form arrays for the attibutes with keys other than below ones 
        "PARTNUM|PRICE|QUANTITY": "itemDetails[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE", // pick only one of the repeating components 
      "itemDetails": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Edit : You can handle the new case through determining an attribute as a key id such as `FIELD2` or `MEMBER_ID`( I picked `FIELD2` ) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@1,FIELD2.&",
        "PARTNUM|PRICE|QUANTITY": "@1,FIELD2.itemDetails[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE", // pick only one of the repeating components 
        "itemDetails": "MANY"
      }
    }
  },
  { // just to order the attributes 
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {// get rid of redundantly generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  I will need to read up more on JoltTransformJSON .

Comment: I have a follow up  question.  This works for the original test scenario.  I am now pulling more data from the database and it is not grouping the way it should.  How do I group for each FIELD2, MEMBER_ID, TIMEPLACED, TOTALPRODUCT, TOTALSHIPPING,TOTALTAX?

Comment: yes, let me do that.

Comment: I updated the original question with a new scenario.  Wasn't able to add it to comment section.

Comment: I've just added the new case @Albert